# PHP Function to Replace CSS Class Names

Tags: php, css

Here is the function

```
function replaceclass($html) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/class="([^"]+)"/', function($m) {

    if(strpos($m[1], "container") !== false) {
        $m[0] = preg_replace("/\s*container\s*/",'product-description-table',$m[0],1);
        }

    if(strpos($m[1], "content-border") !== false) {
    $m[0] = preg_replace("/\s*content-border\s*/",'product-content-border',$m[0],1);
        }

// add as many if conditions with class replacement names as you like
// if(strpos($m[1], "class-name") !== false) {
//     $m[0] = preg_replace("/\s*class-name\s*/",'new-class-name',$m[0],1);
//      }
// add as many if conditions with class replacement names as you like

    return $m[0];

       }, $html);
}
```

This is working great on classes with only one class in them

> Before

`<table class="container">`

> After

`<table class="product-description-table">`

But whenever an element has more than one class, the following format error occurs

> Before

`<table class="container c8">`

> After

`<table class="product-description-tablec8">`

Can anyone think of an easy way to amend this function to detect secondary classes and add the appropriate spacing, `<table class="product-description-table c8">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're removing all the whitespace around the class with the `\s*` patterns in the regexp.

Instead of matching whitespace, use `\b` to match word boundaries.

```
    $m[0] = preg_replace("/\bcontainer\b/",'product-description-table',$m[0],1);
```